# Problema al cambiar background

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo unos cambio en el diseño de la interfaz de mi login de usuario, estoy poniendo un imagen como background pero me tapa mi actionbar y no se por que.

Les dejo el código como lo tengo y una imagen.

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Login"
      android:textColor="#fff"
      android:textSize="30dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:hint="Usuario"
      android:paddingTop="20dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:hint="Password"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:inputType="textPassword"
      android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
      android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#d28f35"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Iniciar Sesion"
      android:layout_above="@+id/tv_result"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_result"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text=""
      android:textSize="26dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te adjunto coodigo de mi manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_oncontrol"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:allowClearUserData="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:parentActivityName=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"

            android:value="mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Splash" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".Login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Login" />
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".Clientes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clientes"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable">
    </meta-data>
     </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Detalle_Cliente"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detalle__cliente"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```

ERROR

> 05-26 16:20:59.179 18139-18139/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile, PID: 18139
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:197)
>                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:126)
>                                                                                       at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Login.onCreate(Login.java:43)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
> 05-26 16:21:01.756 18139-18139/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18139 SIG: 9

Comment: Me parece que no es el background, creo que es una actividad con fondo transparente, como esta definida en tu Manifest.xml???

Comment: te agregue mi codigo del manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando un estilo que no hace visible el ActionBar:

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

No definas el tema o usa uno adecuado como:

```
android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme">
```

Comment: y aqui que tengo que hacer, que tengo que modificar?

Comment: primeramente prueba eliminando android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" para tu actividad login.

Comment: ya lo hice, pero me manda un error

Comment: Que error Hugo?

Comment: ya te adjunte el log que me manda... edite mi publicacion y lo agregue

Comment: he visto, agrega android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme"

Comment: ya pude gracias